# Populating ideal forms select box via jquery get

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to use [Ideal Forms](https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms) for a new responsive site I am working on.  I currently have one radio selector and two drop down selectors.  I am trying to populate the selector with data queried via a cfc.  The jquery I have written for doing this works, as I have another site that uses it, but without using ideal forms.  When I run the script on the new page everything works fine, no errors show up and the data being returned is a correctly formatted json, but the lists do not not get populated.

Here is form:

```
<form id="form1">
    <div>
        <section name="Basic Search">
            <div id="radioDiv">
                <label>Radio Buttons:</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="r1" id="value_1" value="1" checked />1</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="r1" id="value_2" value="2"/>2</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="r1" id="value_3" value="3"/>3</label>
            </div>
            <div id="selectDiv1">
                <label>Select 1:</label>
                <select name="select1" id="select1">
                    <option value="all">All</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="selectDiv2">
                <label>Select 2:</label>
                <select name="select2" id="select2">
                    <option value="all">All</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
$.fn.populateListsBasic = function(){
    $.get("../cfc/mycfc.cfc",{
        method: "getData",
        data: conditionGroup.filter(':checked').val()
        },function(data){
            $.each(data.stuff.otherStuff1,function(key,value){
                $("#select1").append("<option value='" + value + "'>" + value + " (" + data.stuff.otherStuffCount_1[key] + ")</option>");           
            });
            $.each(data.stuff.otherStuff2,function(key,value){
                $("#select2").append("<option value='" + value + "'>" + value + " (" + data.stuff.otherStuffCount_2[key] + ")</option>");
            });
       },"json");
};

$("#form1").populateListsBasic();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a Coldfusion question but.... where does the #makes come from? I don't see that id anywhere in your form? Shouldn't it be:

```
 $.each(data.stuff.otherStuff2,function(key,value){
                $("#select2").append("<option value='" + value + "'>" + value + " (" + data.stuff.otherStuffCount_2[key] + ")</option>");
            });
```

Comment: I agree, but someone asked it to be tagged with coldfusion, that person has since removed that comment.

Comment: Rob... so was the problem the #makes id?

Comment: I was part of the script before I stripped it out the actual identifiers.  I normally rename code when I post on here, I missed that one.